# Como adicionar uma imagem armazenada no firebase storage ao imageView dentro de um infowindow de uma marker?

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps-android-api-2

Eu necessito fazer download de uma imagem do firebase e exibila em um infowindow customizado em um mapa.

```
public class MapaFocosActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback , GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FirebaseStorage storage;
    private StorageReference storageRef;
    private ImageView img;
    private View v;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        .
        .
        .

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_mapa);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://...com");

    }

    .
    .
    .

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        StorageReference imageRef = storageRef.child(marker.getTag().toString()+".jpg");
        v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_window_info, null);
        img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_foco_info);
        Glide.with(MapaFocosActivity.this)
                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                .load(imageRef)
                .into(img);
        File localFile = null;
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        try {
            localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
            final File finalLocalFile = localFile;
            imageRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    // Local temp file has been created


                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle any errors

                }
            });
            bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(finalLocalFile.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("FOTO", "o Arquivo nao foi criado!");
        }

        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        TextView txt_desc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_desc_foco_info);
        txt_desc.setText(marker.getTag()+"\n"+marker.getPosition());
        return v;
    }
}
```

Eu testei e a imagem não aparece. Como eu posso faze-la aparecer no imageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não pode passar a imageReference direto para o Glide como no trecho

```
StorageReference imageRef = storageRef.child(marker.getTag().toString()+".jpg");
Glide.with(MapaFocosActivity.this)
                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                .load(imageRef) // <--- Aqui não pode ser assim.
                .into(img);
```

, tem que passar a URL de download da reference direto.

Eu não uso o Loader, eu pego sempre direto a URL de Download do arquivo e carrego. Mas uma coisa que eu faço eu deixo a permissão de leitura ativada se não tem hora que ele para de abrir a imagem.